# Проблема "Unsupported Java. Your build is currently configured to use Java N and Gradle M" в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle

На ENG-версии сайта [есть такой же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140377/starting-from-which-version-does-gradle-support-java-21).

Я очень долго пытался понять в чём проблема, и перепробовал все указанные способы. Ничего не помогало, а некоторые были просто устаревшими.

Моя ошибка:

```
Unsupported Java. Your build is currently configured to use Java 21 and Gradle 8.3.
```

Причём в документации указано что версии совместимы.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось довольно странным. Несмотря на ошибку связанную с совместимостью версий, сборку крашила `Canary`, которая обновилась втихую, но ошибку выдавала именно версий. Все кто сталкиваются с такой же проблемой, проверьте все свои зависимости проекта.

Я думаю что проблема тут не столько в `Canary`, сколько в самой логике. Если у вас были ошибки с зависимостями до смены версий `Java`/`Gradle`, то попытка сборки (с сохранением ошибок) после смены, будет отображать проблему несовместимости в любом случае, несмотря что проблема вообще не связана.